# Nanoscroll doesn't support multiple contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using Tabulous.js script with NanoScroll.js
Here is my code :

```
<div id="tabs_container" class="nano">
  <div id="tabs-1" class="overthrow content">
   short text
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2" class="overthrow content">
    very long text
  </div>
</div>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
        $(".nano").nanoScroller({scroll: 'top'});
     }
</script>
```

As the first content is short, nano is not used, but for the second content, it should appears.

Content is a class, that's why I though we could use multiple contents. Am I wrong ?

Any advises on this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have only one "nano" class but two content classes.

For every scrolling on your page, you need two of the both classes.

So you may need something like this:

```
<div id="tabs_container" class="nano">
  <div id="tabs-1" class="overthrow content">
   short text
  </div>
</div>
<div id="tabs_container_2" class="nano">
  <div id="tabs-2" class="overthrow content">
    very long text
  </div>
</div>
```

Or somethink like this:

```
<div id="tabs_container" class="nano">
   <div class="content">
     <div id="tabs-1" class="overthrow">
          short text
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-2" class="overthrow">
          very long text
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```